# Let a part of a DIV disappear when it moves out of another DIV?(CSS, JQuery, HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two DIVs. One of those DIVs is inside of another and movable via JQuerys `draggable`. What i want to achieve now is that when i move DIV 2 out of DIV 1 that the part that is outside of DIV 1 should disappear. When you move it back inside it will appear again. What would be the most elegant way to handle that?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example code? (In plunkr or jsfiddle for example)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3a9rj3Lr/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `overflow: hidden` to the container element

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.x {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="x ui-widget-content">
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>
</div>
```